# Pyspark window function with conditions to round number of travelers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

I am using Pyspark and I would like to create a function which performs the following operation:

Given data describing the transactions of train users:

```
+----+----------+--------+-----+
|date|total_trav|num_trav|order|
+----+----------+--------+-----+
|   1|         9|     2.7|    1|
|   1|         9|     1.3|    2|
|   1|         9|     1.3|    3|
|   1|         9|     1.3|    4|
|   1|         9|     1.2|    5|
|   1|         9|     1.1|    6|
|   2|         9|     2.7|    1|
|   2|         9|     1.3|    2|
|   2|         9|     1.3|    3|
|   2|         9|     1.3|    4|
|   2|         9|     1.2|    5|
|   2|         9|     1.1|    6|
+----+----------+--------+-----+
```

I would like to round the numbers of the `num_trav` column based on the order given in the `order` column, while grouping by `date` to obtain the `trav_res` column.
The logic behind it would be something like:

- We group the data by `date`
- For each grouped data (where `date=1` and `date=2`) we have to round numbers to the ceil (`ceil(num_trav)`) always (it doesn´t matter their value, always rounded to the ceil). But taking into account that we have a maximum amount of travelers by group (`total_trav`) which in this case, for both groups would be 9.
- This is where `order` column takes place. You need to start rounding in the order given by that column and checking the amount of travelers you have left for that group.

For example, let's consider this result dataframe and see how the `trav_res` column is formed:

```
+----+----------+--------+-----+--------+
|date|total_trav|num_trav|order|trav_res|
+----+----------+--------+-----+--------+
|   1|         9|     2.7|    1|       3|
|   1|         9|     1.3|    2|       2|
|   1|         9|     1.3|    3|       2|
|   1|         9|     1.3|    4|       2|
|   1|         9|     1.2|    5|       0|
|   1|         9|     1.1|    6|       0|
|   2|         9|     2.7|    1|       3|
|   2|         9|     1.3|    2|       2|
|   2|         9|     1.3|    3|       2|
|   2|         9|     1.3|    4|       2|
|   2|         9|     1.2|    5|       0|
|   2|         9|     1.1|    6|       0|
+----+----------+--------+-----+--------+
```

In the example above, when you group by date, you will have 2 groups which the max amount of travelers is 9 (`total_trav` column).
For group 1 for example yo will start rounding the `num_trav=2.7` to 3 (`trav_res` column), then the `num_trav=1.3` to 2, then `num_trav=1.3` to 2, the `num_trav=1.3` to 2 (this is following the order given), and then for the next ones you have no travelers left, so it doesn't really matter the number they have as there are no travelers left, so they will get `trav_res=0` in both cases.

I have tried some udf functions, but thy seem not to do the job.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve and what is the logic to obtain trav_res column in your second dataframe.

Comment: @AnnaK. I edited the question and explained the example to make it more clear. Let me know if it's still unclear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is based on @AnnaK. answer, with a little addition to it.
This way it takes into accountthat the total number of travelers (total_trav) has to be used, not more, not less.

```
# create ceiling column
df = df_j_test_res.withColumn("num_trav_ceil", F.ceil("num_trav"))

# create cumulative sum column
w = Window.partitionBy("date").orderBy("order")
df = df.withColumn("num_trav_ceil_cumsum", F.sum("num_trav_ceil").over(w))

# impose 0 in trav_res when cumsum exceeds total_trav
df = (df
  .withColumn("trav_res", 
               F.when(F.col("num_trav_ceil_cumsum")<=F.col("total_trav"), 
               F.col("num_trav_ceil")
                     ).when((F.col('num_trav_ceil_cumsum')-F.col('total_trav')>0) & ((F.col('num_trav_ceil_cumsum')-F.col('total_trav')<=1)),
                      1)
              .otherwise(0))
  .select("date", "total_trav", "num_trav", "order", "trav_res"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first apply F.ceil to all rows in num_trav, then create cumsum column based on ceiling values, and then set the ceiling values to zero when cumsum exceeds total_trav as in the code below

```
# create dataframe
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [(1, 9, 2.7, 1),
        (1, 9, 1.3, 2),
        (1, 9, 1.3, 3),
        (1, 9, 1.3, 4),
        (1, 9, 1.2, 5),
        (1, 9, 1.1, 6),
        (2, 9, 2.7, 1),
        (2, 9, 1.3, 2),
        (2, 9, 1.3, 3),
        (2, 9, 1.3, 4),
        (2, 9, 1.2, 5),
        (2, 9, 1.1, 6)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["date", "total_trav", "num_trav", "order"])

# create ceiling column
df = df.withColumn("num_trav_ceil", F.ceil("num_trav"))

# create cumulative sum column
w = Window.partitionBy("date").orderBy("order")
df = df.withColumn("num_trav_ceil_cumsum", F.sum("num_trav_ceil").over(w))

# impose 0 in trav_res when cumsum exceeds total_trav
df = (df
  .withColumn("trav_res", 
               F.when(F.col("num_trav_ceil_cumsum")<=F.col("total_trav"), 
               F.col("num_trav_ceil"))
               .otherwise(0))
  .select("date", "total_trav", "num_trav", "order", "trav_res"))
```

Comment: It's almost correct.
The only thing missing is that the sum of the values in `trav_res` has to be the same as the `total_trav`. 
So if you have 6 travelers in total, you need to arrange those 6, not less. 
I added this little modification to your original code and now i works like a charm.
Thanks so much!!! 
(Code modification posted below as an answer, thanks again, it was just one little thing more to add, but your answer was almost perfect).